# Dynamic routeProvider parameters for angular router

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I am trying to take advantage of the back button's history, and so I am using the traditional $routeProvider and a url of
...`/arg1/something/arg2/something,else/arg3/another/arg4/yet,another/arg5/final`
However, if one `argument` is missing, the following route provider will fail to pass the remaining arguments to the $routeParams:

```
angular.module('myApp', [ … ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/arg1/:args1/arg2/:args2/arg3/:args3/arg4/:args4/arg5/:args5', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

How do I configure the $routeProvider to pass the arguments that are present, (in any order if possible, if not at least in the order that but account for absence of an argument), to the controller without having to declare all 720 (6!) different scenarios of different arguments in different order or not at all?

I then plan to use these values to populate the filters in the controller via the following:

```
    function filterRouteParams (rp){
  if(rp.args1){
    $scope.args1 = rp.args1;
  }
  if(rp.args2){
    $scope.args2 = rp.args2.split(',');
  }
  if(rp.args3){
    $scope.args3 = rp.args3.split(',');
  }
  …
}
```

I am a little familiar with using the `?` query on the URL, but to my knowledge, I don't know how to bind that to the history when I want to update it and also allow for using the back button and maintain the query, but am open to being schooled!

Comment: Do you have to store this information in the route?  I think you could store this information somewhere else that would be more scalable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do I not understand ur question, or it just got complicated?

You just SIMPLY use query string for this purpose. 
It works perfectly fine with back and forward buttons, history push/state.

```
  angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
   .controller('MainController', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
       $scope.$route = $route;
       $scope.$location = $location;
       $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
   })
   .controller('FilterController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
   })
  .config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
     .when('/filter', {
      template: 'inside filter',
      controller: 'FilterController'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/filter'
    });
  });
```

This is the running example of the above code, http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/OS38E38J11FeDS1hyHde/#/filter?c=3&d=4

and Here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OS38E38J11FeDS1hyHde?p=preview).

Comment: How would you use $routeProvider if you changed the path with <form action="search">...<input name="query">....?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way of handling this is through query string parameters, so your route is defined like this:

```
.when('/filter', {
    controller: 'MainController'
})
```

And you just use a URL like `/filter?foo=44&bar=123&baz=true`, or in code:

```
$location.path('/filter').search('foo', $scope.fooValue).search('bar', $scope.barValue);
```

Parameters are optional and be specified in any order as `ngRoute` does not do any validation of param names or values.

To access the values in your controller:

```
.controller('MainController', function($scope, $routeParams) {

    if ($routeParams.foo) {
        // do argument processing
    }

})
```

docs for `$routeParams`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Comment: So i get you are suggesting use the filter query, but how do I get this to be incorporated with the history/push state that an actual route would provide natively.  Isn't the query lost when changing states back and forth?

Comment: Oops, been a while since ive used `ngRoute` — no need to define parameters in url pattern as required by `ui-router`... updated answer, and yes query params are preserved going forward and backwards thru history

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to really understand, but could you use '?' inside your routes ? for example

```
  $routeProvider
  .when('/arg1/:args1?/arg2/:args2?/arg3/:args3?/arg4/:args4?/arg5/:args5?', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainController'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
```

Any of the following URL would be valid

/arg1/arg2/arg3/arg4/arg5
/arg1/value1/arg2/arg3/arg4/arg5/value5
....
/arg1/value1/arg2/value2/arg3/value3/arg4/value4/arg5/value5

Is that what you were looking for?

Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to remove an argument like this
/arg1/arg2/arg4/value4/arg5/value5